# Should There Be OpenGraph / Twitter Card Images & Meta Tags On Every Page?

Tags: seo, open-graph-protocol, twitter-card

What pages on your site need to have OpenGraph & Twitter Card images / meta tags?

All of them? Just the main ones?

Even the pages behind logins, pages that require payment to view, HTTP error pages, login, logout, change password, etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

OpenGraph/Twitter meta tags should be used on any page that anybody is likely to send to someone else on social media or in chat apps. This is the tags' purpose - they make the link appear nicer on social media sites and chat apps.

In practice, this means that all your public-facing pages should have these tags if possible.

> Pages behind logins

No, if they aren't for the public to view.

> Pages that require payment to view

Yes if possible, as people may still share these links on social media. Though if you do this, make sure the tags themselves show up without needing to log in, because crawlers will not log in when scanning for tags.

> HTTP error pages

Not required. People don't share these on social media.

> Login

I would say yes, since someone might share a login page on social media.

> Logout

No, since there's no reason to share it on social media.

> Change password

Yes, someone might share that link.

Comment: What if in order to view the payment pages content, it requires a login also?

Comment: Are these payment pages something that users are likely to share with their friends on social media?

Comment: @user111808 Presumably all "payment pages content" requires a login of some kind?!

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Yes most likely.

Comment: @DocRoot Yes that is correct.

Comment: I think I might need more information to answer that question, then. I've never seen a payment page behind a login that also brings in direct traffic by being shared on social media. What kind of page is it, specifically? What is its purpose, and what is the goal of attracting users from social media directly to the payment page?

Comment: Oh sorry i thought you meant pages that you can access after a user pays from the payment page. My payment page requires a login and then some pages after paying need to have that paid subscription to access content on that page. Hope that makes sense.